# Sub Array comparison in PHP

Tags: php, comparison, arrays

I am trying to compare a sub-array with the indices with a main array. I tried using `array_diff`, `array_intersect_key`, etc, but unable to find the way to proceed, other than using a stupid `for` loop and doing some old school method.

Okay, let me clarify my question. Say, I have two arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => H
    [1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => l
    [4] => o
    [5] => W
    [6] => o
    [7] => r
    [8] => l
    [9] => d
    [10] => !
)

Array
(
    [1] => e
    [5] => W
    [7] => r
    [10] => !
)
```

The first one is the main array of full string: `HelloWorld!` and the second one is the sub-array, which has some selected indices and it's values, given by the users. This can also be wrong, for eg:

```
Array
(
    [1] => F
    [5] => a
    [7] => 6
    [10] => t
)
```

Now, when I pass the first array, it should obviously return `true` and the next one should return `false`. Is this possible with the built-in functions using PHP? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use array_intersect_assoc() if you want to check also if the keys match

```
if (array_intersect_assoc ($a,$b)==$b) {} else {}
```

given that $a is the full array and $b the subset to test against.

Comment: Let me just note that `array_diff_assoc($b, $a)` does the same in a simpler way...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array_diff_assoc($array2, $array1)) {
    echo 'array 2 is not an exact subset of array 1';
}
```

`array_diff_assoc` returns all elements from `$array2` which are not in `$array1`. So if array 2 is a subset of array 1, the return is an empty array, which evaluates to `false`, and otherwise a non-empty array, which evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`array_intersect_uassoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-uassoc.php) is the function you're looking for. It compares based on both keys and values. Here's a quick example:

```
$array1 = array(0 => 'h', 1 => 'e', 2 => 'l', 3 => 'o');
$array2 = array(0 => 'h', 1 => 'e');
$array3 = array(0 => 'h', 1 => 'z');
var_dump(array_intersect_uassoc($array1, $array2, 'strcasecmp'));
var_dump(array_intersect_uassoc($array1, $array3, 'strcasecmp'));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "h"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "e"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "h"
}
```

You then compare the size of the second array with the size of the returned array - if they are equal, all matches are right. If the returned array is smaller - there's a mistake in the second array.

Replace `strcasecmp()` with a callback to your liking and profit :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$array3 = array_diff($array2,$array1); //array2 is checking either present or not in array1
```

and check array3 is empty. if array3 is empty then matched and if not empty than does not matched.

Comment: This is not checking the indices!